# Using a method from inherited class through base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, call, parent

So I couldn't exactly find an answer anywhere.
I have an entity class from which I create all my characters in the game. eg: Player inherits Entity.

Now what I want to do, is call the "Update" method in Player from the entity class. Is this possible? Because I need to do this for every new entity type I create now:

```
 foreach (Entity entity in entityList) {
                if (entity is Zombie) {
                    Zombie zombie = (Zombie)entity;
                    zombie.Update();
                }
                //new character here
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the concept of "update" applies to all entities, you could make `Update` a virtual function of `Entity` and let `Player` override it. Then, inside member functions of `Entity` you would just have to invoke `Update()` on the particular `Entity` object and let the call be dispatched dynamically:

```
foreach (Entity entity in entityList) { entity.Update(); }
```

If `Update()` does not make sense for all `Entity`s, then having them as a virtual function of `Entity` would pollute the interface of that class, and it seems to me that your choice is correct.

You may also consider using the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) if you want to avoid the dynamic downcasts.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `Update()` method in your subclasses. Then, just call `entity.Update()` for any encountered entity. This is what's called polymorphism.